# Save space when downloading Android source

Tags: git, android-source, repository

I'm looking for a way to work with the Android source, and at the same time trying to keep the disk space usage low. Is it possible to `init` some projects as shallow (the ones I only need the latest source and won't be modifying) and others as regular git repos to be able to fetch, push, etc?

EDIT: `repo` has a `--depth=DEPTH` parameter, I was wondering if that parameter could be different for each subproject.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reduce the Size of the Android Source Repository .repo Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761114/reduce-the-size-of-the-android-source-repository-repo-directory)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only realistically practical way to clone and maintain full Android tree is using `repo` utility with `repo init` and `repo sync`. As far as I know, `repo` does not support shallow repositories. But checking out 200-400 of git repositories without using `repo` is extremely difficult.

Also, keep in mind that it is quite common that git metadata which is stored packed in `.git` directories takes less space than just checkout of top commit (however repo plays some tricks with symlinks, so actual data is stored under `.repo`). So, in absolutely best case you are going to save no more than 50% of disk space, but realistically it is going to be much less of a difference.

Finally, with today's typical HDD sizes of 1TB or more, the only possible reason to keep disk usage low is when you are working on SSD. Full Android tree should comfortably fit into about 30GB (even with build out/ directory), which makes rather small 128 GB SSD quite practical solution for Android development.

Comment: I see, thank you. I was wondering if `repo`s `--depth=DEPTH` parameter could be different for each of the subprojects. But if the savings aren't significant then there's not much point to it.

Comment: While hard drive space may not be an issue, internet plans can be a problem (30GB = 25% of my monthly allowance) not to mention the amount of time it would take to download all of the data.
I find the 50% figure interesting. I imagine all of the non-head objects would take up most of the space, rather than just half, but hey I'm just starting in the android world.