# Reduce the Size of the Android Source Repository .repo Directory

Tags: android, git, android-source, repo

I have been switching between several branches of the Android source code with the commands like:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.4_r1.2
repo sync
```

The most recent tag was `android-5.0.0_r2`.  I noticed my .repo directory is now 30 GB in size.  Is that the expected size?  If not, then I'm speculating I have history from the other branches/tags I've used stored in the .repo directory.

Is there a way to reduce the size of the .repo directory?  I would like to limit to only the source/objects/images/etc. I need for the particular branch I'm working on.  HDD space is more important to me than download time.

I see `git gc` is used on .git repositories, but that doesn't work in this case.  Is there an equivalent for .repo repositories?

Note:  I did try `repo prune`, but that did not reduce the size of the .repo directory.

Answer (score 12):

The `-c` flag doesn't seem to be supported any more, but here's what you can do.

At the time of writing, 
`repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-5.1.0_r5` creates **33GB** worth of files.

Adding `--depth=1` reduces this to **21GB**.

Adding `--groups=all,-notdefault,-device,-darwin,-x86,-mips,-exynos5` to exclude devices and components you're not interested in reduces this to **19GB**.

For storage only, you could remove the checked-out files for each .git repository inside .repo/ to save even more space, but I'm not sure how to script this. If you did do this, `repo sync` would check out the "missing" files when needed.

For reference, my complete command line was
`repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-5.1.0_r5 --depth=1 --groups=all,-notdefault,-device,-darwin,-x86,-mips,-exynos5,mako`
so this tree would only work for the Nexus 4. I have *not* yet tried to build from this tree but there's no reason it wouldn't work.

You could also remove projects you're not using by [specifying a local manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21606385/229631), or even work from a compressed filesystem like btrfs with the right mount options, but I'm unsure of the performance impact.

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but I *think* you can use the `-c` switch to only download the branches you currently need.

> With that flag, repo will only download the revision (branch) that is specified in the manifest, not all the branches that are on the remote server. It will thus save us quite some space, and again it will take less time to download.

Source and more info: http://xda-university.com/as-a-developer/repo-tips-tricks

Comment: While that would help minimize the space of a single branch, I don't think that helps if I download multiple branches.  I will still end up with extra content in the places where branches don't overlap.

Comment: I don't think -c is supported any more. There's no reference to it in the current repo source.

Comment: -c is supported. See https://source.android.com/setup/develop/repo#sync