# aosp repository android-7.1.2_r36 not complete after download 42GB

Tags: android, android-source, repo, rom

I started downloading aosp **android-7.1.2_r36** by following command:

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-7.1.2_r36
$ repo sync
```

After 10 hours, downloaded file size is 42GB and downloading yet!

I had seen in websites that repository size is about 20-25GB finally 35GB.

Is this (over than 42gb) normal?
How big is this repository?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Requirements page of source.android.com](https://source.android.com/setup/build/requirements):

> Your development workstation should meet or exceed these hardware
>   requirements:
>
> - A 64-bit environment is required for Android 2.3.x (Gingerbread) and higher versions, including the master branch. You can compile
>     older versions on 32-bit systems.
> - **At least 100GB of free disk space to checkout the code and an extra 150GB to build it**. If you conduct multiple builds, you will need
>     even more space.
> - If you are running Linux in a virtual machine, you need at least 16GB of RAM/swap.

So 42 GB seems fine.

Comment: i use ubuntu 18.04 on pc (not virtual) with cpu core i5 7th and 16GB RAM and ssd(250) and hdd(1TB)

Comment: my ubuntu is on ssd and repository directory on hdd(ext4 partition 350GB).
now downloading process not complete but repository downloaded size is 57GB!
my internet connection is not reliable and disconnect some times during my download.because this i guess the repo download files again

Comment: The next time you run `repo sync`, repo should restart from where it stops/failed last time. Watch the output of `repo sync` you should see that the fetch is pretty fast at the beginning because the files are already downloaded from the remote. When the output begins to slow done it means repo is downloading new project.

Comment: yes you'r right.
it show fetched files but downloaded size is big and this confused me.
on the other hand i need source for phone and tablet but i seen tv and wear logs in terminal when downloading. 

how can i download just for phone?

Comment: I don't know how to do it but I don't think it will make you won mush space. On my computer my aosp (master branch) size is 61 GB. So you are almost there.

Comment: now downloaded size is 78GB and downloading yet!
what's your comment?
do i stop downloading?
i see following every time:


`error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
remote: Sending approximately 13.28 GiB ...        
remote: Counting objects: 595, done  `

Comment: About the error, no idea. To try to reduce the source size you may take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761114/reduce-the-size-of-the-android-source-repository-repo-directory