# repo sync aosp of android-4.3_r1, the size of the .repo directory reach 70G

Tags: android, android-source, repo

I have download the Android source code with the commands like:

```
repo init -u https://aosp.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/platform/manifest -b android-4.3_r1 --repo-url=git://codeaurora.org/tools/repo.git --repo-branch=caf-stable
repo sync
```

The size of android-4.3_r1 source code is about 7G.
But the size of .repo directory is reach to 70G.
[image: size of AOSP]

Enter .repo directory and found there is a project-objects directory sizeof 70G.
[image: size of .repo]

Why is the repo directory so huge?
What dose the project-objects directory use for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's OK.

`.repo/project-objects` contains [Git Objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)

When you use `repo`, Git objects are not stored directly in the repository. If you take a look at the `.git` directory of one of the repository of your workspace you will see a lot of symbolic link to `.repo/project-objects`.

For example:

```
$ cd bionic/.git
$ la
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hugo hugo   41 juin  22 15:24 [2]  HEAD
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hugo hugo   38 juin  22 15:24 [3]  config -> ../../.repo/projects/bionic.git/config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hugo hugo   55 juin  22 15:24 [4]  description -> ../../.repo/project-objects/aosp/bionic.git/description
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hugo hugo   49 juin  22 15:24 [5]  hooks -> ../../.repo/project-objects/aosp/bionic.git/hooks
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hugo hugo 440K juil.  3 15:42 [6]  index
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hugo hugo   48 juin  22 15:24 [7]  info -> ../../.repo/project-objects/aosp/bionic.git/info
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hugo hugo   36 juin  22 15:24 [8]  logs -> ../../.repo/projects/bionic.git/logs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hugo hugo   51 juin  22 15:24 [9]  objects -> ../../.repo/project-objects/aosp/bionic.git/objects
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hugo hugo   43 juin  22 15:24 [10] packed-refs -> ../../.repo/projects/bionic.git/packed-refs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hugo hugo   36 juin  22 15:24 [11] refs -> ../../.repo/projects/bionic.git/refs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hugo hugo   52 juin  22 15:24 [12] rr-cache -> ../../.repo/project-objects/aosp/bionic.git/rr-cache
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hugo hugo   39 juin  22 15:24 [13] shallow -> ../../.repo/projects/bionic.git/shallow
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hugo hugo   47 juin  22 15:24 [14] svn -> ../../.repo/project-objects/aosp/bionic.git/svn
```

Another interesting things to note is the two step in `repo sync`:

- the first one is the fetch, during which Git object will be downloaded from the server to the .repo/project-objects
- the second one is the checkout phase where the files are copied from the `.repo/project-objects` to the working directory

It means that if you delete all the directories except the `.repo` and sync again the fetch phase will be pretty fast (depending on new modifications on the remote) and that repo sync will mostly do copy to the working directory during the checkout phase.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there anyway to reduce the size of .repo directory?

Comment: You may take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761114/reduce-the-size-of-the-android-source-repository-repo-directory